TypeError: SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor
const unirest = require('unirest'); 
const SocksProxyAgent = require('socks-proxy-agent');
 
// Define your SOCKS5 proxy
const proxy = 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1234';
 
// Create a SOCKS5 proxy agent
const agent = new SocksProxyAgent(proxy);
 
// Set up the request with the proxy agent
unirest.get('https://google.com')
  .proxy(agent)
  .end(function (response) {
    console.log(response.body);
  });

I am using above script to setup proxy setting with socks5 but I am getting "TypeError: SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor" this error. Please help me to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.
I want to setup the proxy with socks5 in firefox browser

Try const { SocksProxyAgent } = require('socks-proxy-agent'); instead. That's what seems to be being used here and  here. There's an explanation for the {} here: Curly brackets (braces) in Node.js 'require' statement
